# get data from a php page in a synchronous way

Tags: php, ajax

I have a file `add.php` which is adding two numbers and returns the result.
My other file `list.php` contains a list with numbers that need to be added

```
$list = array ( 0=> 2,3
1=>4,5
2=>6,7);
```

This array can be longer so I have to read it's data with a `for` loop like this:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($list);$i++) {
//something needs to be done here
}
```

What I want to do is to add all the pairs with one submit button.
My problem is that every pair of numbers has to be added only if the previous one has got a result.
I want for example a result array to change like this :

```
No1  | No2  | result   
---- | ---- | -------- 
2    | 3    | on queue 
---- | ---- | -------- 
4    | 5    | on queue 
---- | ---- | -------- 
6    | 7    | on queue 

No1  | No2  | result   
---- | ---- | -------- 
2    | 3    | 5        
---- | ---- | -------- 
4    | 5    | on queue 
---- | ---- | --------
6    | 7    | on queue

No1  | No2  | result
---- | ---- | --------
2    | 3    | 5
---- | ---- | --------
4    | 5    | 9
---- | ---- | --------
6    | 7    | on queue

No1  | No2  | result
---- | ---- | --------
2    | 3    | 5
---- | ---- | --------
4    | 5    | 9
---- | ---- | --------
6    | 7    | 13
```

I tried with ajax at first, like this:

```
<script> function loadDoc(fid1,fid2) {
         var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
         }
         };
         xhttp.open('POST', 'play2.php', true);
         xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
         xhttp.send('number1=$No1&number2=$No2');
         } 
         </script>
```

where `$No1`,`$No2` are `$list[$i][0],$list[$i][1]`. 
So, this one failed, I guess cause of the asynchronous nature of ajax but i have no other ideas about how to do it.
What I want to do is more complicated than this but it was easier to explain it with this example. 
Also i would like to do this without database calls if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it using ajax with async:false like this

```
<script>
         $.ajax({ 
             type: "POST",   
             url: "play2.php", 
             data: {number1:"'.$No1.'" , number2:"'.$No2.'"}, 
             async: false,
             success : function (data) {
                 $("#content").replaceWith(data);
                }
            });
</script>
```

I put this in a for loop to send all the pairs of values and it worked as i wanted.